# Interchanging positions of Gell-Mann matrices with Dirac matrices, Pauli matrices

Tags: spinors, yang-mills, dirac-matrices, color-charge

The anti-commutation relations for Gamma matrices $\big\{\gamma ^\mu , \gamma ^\nu \big\} = 2g ^{\mu \nu} $ can be used for interchanging positions of the respective matrices in a given expression, for example : $-i\gamma ^\mu \gamma ^2 \gamma ^0 = i\gamma ^2 \gamma ^0 \gamma ^{\mu} $. **Question -** Do we have any similar prescription for interchanging positions (of *objects*) that don't belong to the same **space**, for examlple: can we interchange the positions of  $\lambda _A $ with $\tau _2 $ or (say) $\tau _2 $ with $\gamma _5 $ in the following expression (via some rule):
$\bar {\psi} \gamma ^0 \lambda _A \tau _2 \gamma _5 \gamma _0 \psi $ ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question:

The Gell-Mann matrices are the generators of the $SU(3)$ Lie algebra - $3 \times 3$ matrices analogous to the $SU(2)$ matrices of dimension $2 \times2$ - the Pauli spin matrices.

The Dirac or gammas matrices as above are of dimensions $4 \times4$.

Given these matrices are all of different dimensions they cannot be multiplied and therefore do not “mix”, so there is no commutation relation that involve these three different matrices.

Comment: since the matrices do not “mix”, interchanging their positions has no meaning whatsoever, or, they can be interchanged in an expression without any consequence? Thanks

Comment: The point is you cannot put them together in the first place. It would be meaningless. You cannot multiply 3x3 4x4 or 2x2. This is just a consequence of matrix algebra. Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: they can be multiplied - look at equations (4) and (6) here - [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.3907.pdf)

Comment: These matrices are a representation of quarks in a higher dimensional - flavour- space and not the 2x2 Pauli matrices you stated above. Very interesting paper though. Thanks for the read. Cheers

Comment: you're welcome! But my question remains the same - can we/can't we interchange the positons of $\lambda _A$'s, $\gamma $'s and $\tau $'s (strictly with reference to the paper shared above) without any consequence? Thanks

Comment: @user263315  of course you can.  , ,  matrices are in direct product, and so act on different direct-product factors of $\psi=\psi_1\otimes\psi_2\otimes\psi_3$, leaving the other two factors alone. This is what the notation *means* in the first place.

Comment: @CosmasZachos  OP was not talking about direct products which would of course change things and you’d be right. OP was talking about simple matrix multiplication I believe.

Comment: @joseph h. That's just the point. Matrix multiplication is wildly off the mark for matrices acting on different factors of the tensor/Cartesian product. He has simply not thought through the formal structure, and so has not understood what standard texts detail....

Comment: @CosmasZachos Exactly. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Add indices to all matrices. The only thing you should then worry about is whether they are real or Grassmann numbers.